# Why does this Android alarm with a pending intent crash?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-syncadapter

I have a very simple piece of code that is used to schedule my next sync operation.  It is running inside the SyncAdapter that extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter -- thus uses its context.  The PendingIntent it started for the BroadcastReceiver "MyService" which only manages the SyncAdapter.

I am just trying to schedule it to recur in 24 hours.

```
private void scheduleNextSync(Long timeFromNow) {
    Intent intentSync = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);
    intentSync.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SYNC);
    intentSync.addCategory("android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE");
    intentSync.putExtra(MySyncAdapter.EXTRA_SYNC_TYPE, "");
    intentSync.putExtra(MySyncAdapter.EXTRA_RESOLVE_METAID, false);

    int flags = 0;
    int request = REQUEST_SYNC_ALL;
    PendingIntent piSync = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), request, intentSync, flags);
    //
    Log.i(TAG, "schedulePendingSync: " + piSync.toString());
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(request, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeFromNow, piSync);
}
```

Log output:

```
01-20 22:42:18.864 W/dalvikvm(14447): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020950)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1253)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:174)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:139)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at com.mysyncadpter.android.MySyncAdapter.scheduleNextSync(MySyncAdapter.java:145)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at com.mysyncadpter.android.MySyncAdapter.access$2(MySyncAdapter.java:131)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at com.mysyncadpter.android.MySyncAdapter$1.run(MySyncAdapter.java:123)
01-20 22:42:18.919 E/AndroidRuntime(14447):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` and `alarm.set` use the request `REQUEST_SYNC_ALL`
I can't find that constant in the [Alarm doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), nor the [PendingIntent doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

Maybe I am out of sync with the latest SDK :)

Comment: That is my own definition ... is that a reserved value?  I have two requests: 100 and 101 that "REQUEST_SYNC_FIRST_TIME" or "REQUEST_SYNC_ALL."

Comment: I think for `PendingIntent`, it is fine but for `Alarm`, according to the doc, the options are one of `ELAPSED_REALTIME`, `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`, `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP`.

Comment: Perfect - what a bonehead on my part to think this was just a code for my usage.  I was planning on switching on its value when the trigger popped.  My crash is gone.